# What precisely does dlgStretch do in Eagle PCB?

Tags: eaglecad, script

The manual of ULP says that this command "Defines an empty stretchable space in a box layout context". It gives the below trivial example:

```
   dlgHBoxLayout {
     dlgStretch(1);
     dlgPushButton("+OK")    { dlgAccept(); };
     dlgPushButton("Cancel") { dlgReject(); };
   }
```

This would be used as part of a bigger script containing dlgDialog. The thing is that changing the value of the parameter passed to this function makes no different at all. I am confused what this function is supposed to be used for.

Answer (score 1):

The stretch factor does not matter when there is only a single space.

For multiple stretchable spaces, the factor specifies how much of the available space is allocated to each space object.

Try something like this:

```
dlgHBoxLayout {
  dlgStretch(1);
  dlgPushButton("+OK")    { dlgAccept(); };
  dlgStretch(2);
  dlgPushButton("Cancel") { dlgReject(); };
  dlgStretch(3);
}
```